# How to extend rollup.config.js in Ionic2 app?

Tags: ionic2

Here is my solution, but it might not be the proper way:

Create a `rollup.config.js` file under your app root folder.
In `package.json` file, add the following code:

```
"config": 
{
"ionic_rollup": "./rollup.config.js" 
}
```

In the `rollup.config.js`, import the existing Ionic rollup config:

```
var rollupConfig = require('./node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/config/rollup.config.js');

// Extend your config here.

module.exports = rollupConfig;
```